# Apple Startup Image not showing up

Tags: iphone, safari, mobile-safari

Cannot seem to get the Apple Startup image to appear on our mobile (not native) app.

I have:

1. Added meta tag -
2. Tried both 320x480 and 320x460 .png images and nothing
3. Tried to use an absolute url
4. looked at logs and image seems to be called just not appearing on iphone (or iPad)
5. Using Apple naming conventions, like: Default.png, Default@2x.png, etc.

Help!

Doug

Comment: Can you show us the meta tag you used? The startup image will only work on sites you've saved to the home screen, you don't need to name it Default.png, and @2x doesn't work on the web end of things, only native apps.

Answer (score 5):

You can not have a landscape startup image on an iPhone. Landscape images ONLY work on the iPad. Also, you must use the proper size on the iPhone, or it will not display at all.

This will add a Splash Screen to your Web App. Below are the sizes you’ll need for both iPad and iPhone/iPod Touch, these include the status bar area as well.

iPad Landscape – 1024 x 748

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="img/splash-screen-1024x748.png" />
```

iPad Portrait – 768 x 1004

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="img/splash-screen-768x1004.png" />
```

iPhone/iPod Touch Portrait – 320 x 480 (standard resolution)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash-screen-320x460.png" />
```

iPhone/iPod Touch Portrait – 640 x 960 pixels (Retina Display high-resolution)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x960" href="img/splash-screen-640x960.png" />
```

If creating a Web App for iPad compatibility it’s recommended that both Landscape and Portrait sizes are used.

Comment: There is a better answer that works (and has been accepted) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643817/ios-iphone-web-app-splash-screen-not-showing-up