# iOS/iPhone: Web App Splash Screen Not Showing Up

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, media-queries, splash-screen

I have the following code in the `<head>` of my web app, but I'm just getting a white screen on my iPhone 3GS while the DOM loads instead of the splash screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

<!--STYLES-->

<!--SCRIPTS-->

<!-- iPhone LAUNCHSCREEN-->
<link href="includes/images/apple-launch-480h.png" sizes="320x480" media="(device-height: 480px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPhone (Retina) LAUNCHSCREEN-->
<link href="includes/images/apple-launch-480h2X.png" sizes="640x920" media="(device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPhone 5+ LAUNCHSCREEN-->
<link href="includes/images/apple-launch-568h.png" sizes="640x1136" media="(device-height: 568px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

**How can I get my splash screen to display correctly on all versions of the iPhone?** Code not shown, but my web app icons are working when added to the homepage. I'm using jQuery Mobile to build this web app.

I have also confirmed that the PNG images are exactly the correct sizes and I have deleted the web app icon, refreshed, and re-added to the homescreen multiple times. None of the solutions I've found on StackOverflow have worked for me. I have not tried the JavaScript solutions, because I'm sure there is a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `sizes` attribute works for `apple-touch-icon`s but it doesn't work for `apple-touch-startup-image`s. The only way to target the startup images is with media queries. Adam's answer is good but relies on the `<link>`s being in a particular order since the media queries are under-specified. Here are the fully-qualified media queries:

```
<!-- iPhone -->
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png"
      media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPhone (Retina) -->
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png"
      media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPhone 5 -->
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png"
      media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (portrait) -->
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: portrait)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (landscape) -->
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: landscape)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) -->
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: portrait)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) -->
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: landscape)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Also note that certain viewports will cause your web app to be letterboxed on the iPhone 5:

```
<!-- Letterboxed on iPhone 5 -->
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=320">
<!-- Not letterboxed on iPhone 5 -->
<meta name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=320.1">
```

I maintain [a Gist with a minimal iOS web app](https://gist.github.com/2222823), including startup images and icons. If you want some more commentary, I also wrote [a blog post about iPhone 5 startup images](http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/09/20/iphone-5-web-app-startup-image/).

Comment: Awesome! I'll try these out. Thanks!

Comment: If it helps anyone, the iPhone 6 splash sizes are here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26057714/188926

Comment: @TaylorFausak could you make and provide a template GIT project including the startup screen images ? I do not think any is available and I never succeeded yet to see any splash screen on a home screen web app

Comment: I am not interested in maintaining a Git repository for this. Everything you need, other than the images themselves, is available in the Gist. (You can even clone the Gist like a regular Git repository!)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the dimensions to use:

```
<!-- iPhone -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-startup-iPhone.jpg" media="(device-width: 320px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone (Retina) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-startup-iPhone-RETINA.jpg" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone Tall (Retina) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-startup-iPhone-Tall-RETINA.jpg" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x1096">

<!-- iPad (portrait) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-startup-iPad-Portrait.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPad (landscape) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-startup-iPad-Landscape.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-startup-iPad-RETINA-Portrait.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-startup-iPad-RETINA-Landscape.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Comment: You used `640 x 1096` for the iPhone Tall, but on [Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) they say it should be `640 x 1136`. Which is right?

Comment: You're not accounting for the 40 pixels taken up by the status bar. The `640 x 1136` is for an app launch image. `640 x 1096` is correct.