# Correct Size for apple-touch-startup-image in iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: html, media-queries, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Wanting to see if my math and media queries are correct here, as I cannot find this info anywhere.

```
<!-- iOS 8 iPhone 6 (portrait) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/apple-touch-startup-image-750×1294.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)">
<!-- iOS 8 iPhone 6 (landscape) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/apple-touch-startup-image-710x1334.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)">
<!-- iOS 8 iPhone 6 Plus (portrait) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/apple-touch-startup-image-1242×2148.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)">
<!-- iOS 8 iPhone 6 Plus (landscape) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/apple-touch-startup-image-1182x2208.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)">
```

Comment: Okay? So, what's the question, what problems are you (potentially) having with your math and media-queries?

Comment: LOL, okay I guess I could have been more clear.  The dimensions for the 4 lines of code, 750×1294, 710x1334, 1242×2148, 1182x2208. Are those correct?

Comment: Why would dimensions be different between portrait and landscape for each device (other than the obvious swapping of width and height)?

Comment: You need to deduct 20px or 40px (or 60px for the iPhone 6 Plus) for the statusbar.

Answer (score 9):

Edit: I have removed incorrect information from my post, what you had placed is correct minus the iPhone 6 landscape mode, and swap the width/height for iPhone 6+ landscape.

```
<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<link href="750x1294.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone 6+ Portrait -->
<link href="1242x2148.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone 6+ Landscape -->
<link href="2208x1182.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

I had previously made a mistake by using startup image sizes the same as the device, and they simply don't show, the correct image sizes must be used.

Comment: [That same mobilexweb.com link](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios8-iphone6-web-developers-designers) you sourced (which is a great read, I already went through it) also states device-width of 375px and 414px. Which goes along with the apple-touch-startup-image media attributes I already have in place for iPad and older iPhones.

Comment: iPhone 6 Plus only allows for landscape, I just found out. So that eliminates one line of code. Still have to test on the Plus before I post my completed code snippet.

Comment: Ahh yes your absolutely right about the pixels, there's so much conflicting info about at the moment, but that seems to be the most complete. Does the iPhone 6+ only support landscape (not portrait views), or is it the only device that supports portrait and landscape?

Comment: The iPhone 6+ has portrait and landscape. The iPhone 6 does not have landscape for the home screen, sort of makes sense.

Comment: @KenEdwards why does it make sense for the iPhone 6 not to have landscape mode? iPhone 5S did have it. Just wondering what's the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here is my proposed answer, based on the excellent answer by Adam Smith:

```
<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<link href="750x1294.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone 6+ Portrait -->
<link href="1242x2148.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone 6+ Landscape -->
<link href="1182x2208r.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Note the 6+ landscape image must be rotated to the right by 90° and must be sized 1182x2208.  This is consistent with the landscape startup images for the iPad.  If you are a webapp developer and have an iPhone 6+ please test this answer and comment.   Thanks!

Comment: 1182 x 2208 rotated by 90° is 2208 x 1182. The landscape image must saved in landscape mode, it needs to be 2208 wide and 1182 high.

Comment: @AdamSmith at least for iPhone 5, the startup images must be **always** in vertical position.

Comment: If somebody who has an iPhone 6+ can test what the right answer it, that would be real nice!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the sizes has to be slightly different, as described in https://dev.to/oskarlarsson/designing-native-like-progressive-web-apps-for-ios-510o I had to define the following link for iPhone 6s:

```
<link href="/apple-launch-750x1334.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Only after that the startup image appears on iPhone 6s.