# Startup images for web apps with iOS 8

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, ios8, mobile-safari

After the launch of iOS 8 I wrote a simple web app and now I was wondering if startup images still make sense and if they are still used.
Since I don't get a launch image in my web app I was wondering if safari still supports it under iOS 8 
I used following code as it is pre-given from apple's guidelines

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26057714/118091

You will have specify sizes and orientation support.

```
<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<link href="750x1294.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone 6+ Portrait -->
<link href="1242x2148.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone 6+ Landscape -->
<link href="2208x1182.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Comment: okay thanks, this worked. But unfortunately iPhone 5 does not load the startup image with iOS 8. 
I used this code: 
 <link href="iPhone5.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

Comment: seems like I used the wrong height (instead of 1096px I used 1136px)